# Spring Boot Java Kafka configuration, overwrite port

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Spring Boot + Kafka. This is my current, pretty simple configuration for Kafka:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

}
```

This configuration works pretty fine and is able to connect to Kafka instance on default Kafka port: `9092`

Right now I need to change the port, let's say on `9093`.

How to update this Kafka configuration in order to be able to connect on `9093`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think something like this in your properties file will do the trick

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9093
```

you can specify comma separated list of host:port